# Cypher Language list of reserved words?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Is there a list of reserved words for Neo4j Cypher? I'd like to avoid any pitfalls others have discovered, reserved words have bitten me in the past with other projects.

Answer (score 3):

There's no comprehensive list of reserved words in the documentation. For the upcoming version 2.0, the keywords are defined in a single file, with possible abbreviations (like asc/desc):

https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/2.0/community/cypher/src/main/scala/org/neo4j/cypher/internal/parser/v2_0/Strings.scala

Version 1.9 is a bit less well organized, most are in https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/2.0/community/cypher/src/main/scala/org/neo4j/cypher/internal/parser/v1_9/Base.scala, "create unique" is in https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/2.0/community/cypher/src/main/scala/org/neo4j/cypher/internal/parser/v1_9/CreateUnique.scala

Comment: Good point. Your 2.0 list is more comprehensive than mine. "unique" is not actually reserved, although "create" is.

Comment: BTW, the parser is probably changing soon, so it may not have the same keyword requirements. Check out the "experimental parser" branch.

Comment: Link #1 is now dead.

Answer (score 1):

For Neo4j there is a reference card that i like to use:    https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-refcard/current/

Answer (score 0):

The only truly reserved words (as of 2.0 M03) are (and, sorry if this is incomplete, this is off the top of my head):

```
START
MATCH
WHERE
WITH
RETURN
FOREACH
CREATE
SET
UNION
DELETE
REMOVE   
CASE
WHEN
THEN
ASC
DESC
```

There are functions/aggregation functions as well, but the parser is smart enough to be able to allow things like:

```
RETURN count(*) as count
```

I wouldn't worry about it--it will give you a reasonable error if you hit one of these cases anyway. Like so:

```
Query:
START match=node(*) 
RETURN match
Error: reserved keyword
"START match=node(*) "
```

Comment: What about `LIMIT`?

Comment: @programmer5000 this list is totally outdated these days. They rewrote the parser going into 2.1 or somewhere around there, and it's much smarter and more flexible about things in context.

`match (match)
return match as return
limit 1`